# Cannot access deserialized JSON Object property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using .NET 4 and trying to parsing string to Json object as below

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"biofractal\"}");
var i = result.Name;
```

As soon as my debugger tries to cross the second line, I get an error

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
```

Comment: You acces JObject via indexes, e.g. `result["Name"]` should work.

Comment: I've tried your code (in .net 4.5) and it works fine (result.Name = "biofractal") - this is with json Newtonsoft dll v5.0.6 16206

Comment: Thanks. My newtonsoft dll is 3.5. But Ben's solution worked for me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Both `result.Name` and `result["Name"]` work in .net 4.5 and Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EVkEh7